# Change color of table row when an input within is focused

Tags: php, jquery, css, colors

Suppose I have a table like this with `<tr>` and `<td>` inside PHP loop :

```
   //Some code...
   echo "<table id='rowClick'>";
   while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result){

    echo "<tr><td><input type='text' value='{$row['item']}'></td></tr>";
}
    echo "</table>";
//Rest of code
```

I've used a CSS :

```
table tr.active{
    background:red;
}
```

And For JQuery :

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#rowClick").children("tbody").children("tr").children("td").keydown(function(){
        $(this.parentNode).toggleClass("active");
    });
     $("#rowClick").children("tbody").children("tr").children("td").keyup(function(){
        $(this.parentNode).toggleClass("active");
    });
});
</script>
```

I'm not so familiar with JQuery. All I want is that when user select `<td>` *input field* ( or being focused ) in any row, the color of the `<tr>` will be changed . According to the above jquery it works but not as expected, because each time I select input field it turns red, then when selecting next one it returns back to default table color and so on.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using keydown/keyup. Sounds like you want to use [focusin](https://api.jquery.com/focusin/) and [focusout](https://api.jquery.com/focusout/). Also, instead of doing `toggleClass`, perhaps you should be doing an `addClass` on focusin and a `removeClass` on focusout?

Comment: Let me try this , i'll inform you back with the results !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#rowClick").find("input").on("focus", function(){
      $(this).closest("tr").addClass("active");
    }).on("blur", function() {
      $(this).closest("tr").removeClass("active");
    })
});
```

I'm targeting the `input` from the table to look for focus/blur, then from the inputs I'm targeting the closest parent `tr` to highlight.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1k0hd5y2/)

If you want to highlight the `td` instead, just target that instead:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1k0hd5y2/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've tried your code and works exactly what i'm hoping for, but I realized that when moving to the next field inside same row It turns back to its default color ( I meant `<td>Color Changed</td><td>Here color turns back to default </td>` ). Color changes only when moving down the same column.

Comment: @AliHamra, I think you are saying you want to target the TDs now rather than the TRs, please check my edit at the bottom. (note that you will also have to change your CSS if you are using `tr.active`)

Comment: Ok I've used your updated answer, and now It works by clicking on each `<td>` input no matter where it is placed. Thank you very much, just one question is it possible that color will change also when moving to another input field using keyboard arrow keys? I've tried it now and it seems that this also return back to its default color. I mean suppose using right or left arrow..Right now it works only up and down keys...I'm so sorry

Comment: Arrow keys will not change the focus... unless you have some js that is doing that for you?

Comment: oh okay, I though its possible to do it in JQuery. I've used JS for field validating purpose only.

Comment: @AliHamra, sorry, I am not sure what you are asking. Pushing the arrow keys on the keyboard up/down/left/right will just change the cursor placement within the input.

Comment: Okay, I'm using arrow keys to jump to the next input field quickly rather than using mouse clicks ( By which it will be focused ). I have a page full of input fields that are meant to collect new qty for each item. That's why I wanted this color option so I can realize which row I'm editing related to its item number.

Comment: @AliHamra, How are the arrow keys jumping? In an input, up arrow will move your cursor to the beginning of the input... it will not move to a different input. Other arrow keys have similar behavior. If you have JS that handles the arrow key input and does something with it, you'd have to ask a separate question about why that isn't doing all you want I think.

Answer (score 1):

You say when it is focused but I don't understand why you use keydown/keyup? they are used for keyboard events. [read here](https://api.jquery.com/keydown/)

Try:

```
$("#rowClick tr input").on("focus", function(){
    $("#rowClick tr").removeClass("active");
    $(this).parents("tr").addClass("active")

})
```

You assign the click event on the tr which is not on the td but it will bubble up to the tr and since you are changing the color of the entire row this is cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , based on your code it works only when I select input field using mouse click, I want the new color to be changed when field always focused , either by mouse click or key event.

Comment: If user moves focus to another item on page (outside of table) this wouldn't remove the active class. You would need a `focusout`or `blur` event to do that, I think

Comment: That was not included in the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use the focus and focusout events of the textbox to target its parent `<tr>` and add and remove the active class as necessary:

```
$(function() {
     $('#rowClick input').on('focus', function() {
          $(this).closest('tr').addClass('active');
     }).on('focusout', function() {
          $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('active');
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since focusin/focusout events bubble (unlike blur), you can simplify things by actually attaching the listener to the tr, rather than the inputs. This has the benefit that if you are changing between inputs in the same row, it won't fire (because it isn't needed...you're still in the same row). Like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#rowClick tr").focusin(function(){
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }).focusout(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
    });
});
```

```css
table tr.active{
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id='rowClick'>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```